How to reset VSCode workspace settings?
Recently, I was having trouble with VSCode collapsing my code and I'm unable revert the changes.
How can I reset my VSCode workspace completely?

This question is similar to: How do I factory reset Visual Studio Code or Delete Folders. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

VSCode stores it's workspace data in the following path:
%AppData%\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage
You can look inside each folder JSON file and check which workspace you want to reset. Then it is just a matter of deleting the folder.
